# How to select a single object in video frame clicking mouse on it?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm working on a project in which I have to select an object using a mouse click on it and then I have to find the distance between the object and camera.

here is my code :

```html
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import datetime


def find_marker(image):
    # convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and detect edges
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 35, 125)

    # find the contours in the edged image and keep the largest one;
    # we'll assume that this is our piece of paper in the image
    _, cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

    # compute the bounding box of the of the paper region and return it
    return cv2.minAreaRect(c)


def distance_to_camera(knownWidth, focalLength, perWidth):
    # compute and return the distance from the maker to the camera
    return (knownWidth * focalLength) / perWidth


# initialize the known distance from the camera to the object, which
#, in this case, is 24 inches
KNOWN_DISTANCE = 24.0

# initialize the known object width, which in this case, the piece of
# paper is 12 inches wide
KNOWN_WIDTH = 11.0

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="path to the (optional) video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# if the video path was not supplied, grab the reference to the
# camera
if not args.get("video", False):
    vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    time.sleep(2.0)

# otherwise, load the video
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])


# loop over the frames from the video stream


frame = vs.read()
marker = find_marker(frame)
# otherwise, load the video

focalLength = (marker[1][0] * KNOWN_DISTANCE) / KNOWN_WIDTH

while (1):
    # grab the frame from the threaded video stream and resize it
    # to have a maximum width of 400 pixels

    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    if frame is None:
        break



    marker = find_marker(frame)
    # image = cv2.imread(frame)


    inches = distance_to_camera(KNOWN_WIDTH, focalLength, marker[1][0])

    # draw a bounding box around the image and display it
    box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(marker))
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, "%.2fft" % (inches / 12),
                    (frame.shape[1] - 200, frame.shape[0] - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    2.0, (0, 255, 0), 3)
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    ts = timestamp.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p")
    cv2.putText(frame, ts, (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

In this code, I'm able to find the object distance but the problem is it's detecting multiple objects at a time and giving distances.

what I want is to select one object at a time and make square ROI on it using mouse click function.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, noticed `# paper is 12 inches wide`
`KNOWN_WIDTH = 11.0`, just pointing it out

Comment: @Max I haven't deleted the comment but yes I'm using reference paper width 11.0 inches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setMouseCallback function to detect mouse clicks on an image in OpenCV. First of all create a named window and then call the setMouseCallback function with that image and the function to detect mouse clicks. The while loop will run continuously until you have selected 'c' on keyboard to break and finish collecting points. Xpt and Ypt return lists of the x and y pixel coordinates of where you clicked on the image. If you click in the wrong place press 'r' and it will reset the lists and create a new image to click on.

```
clone = image.copy()
cv2.namedWindow('image you want to click on')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image you want to click on', click_and_extract_points)

while 1:
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord('r'):  # if mouse clicks done incorrectly, press 'r'. Resets arrays and map image.
        Xpt = []
        Ypt = []
        image = clone.copy()

    elif key == ord('c'):
        break

def click_and_extract_points(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        Xpt.append(x)
        Ypt.append(y)
        print(Xpt, Ypt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in function provided by opencv:

```
roi = cv2.selectROI(image)
```

It creates/displays "ROI selection" window, shows frame. Use mouse to select bounding box dragging mouse pointer from top-left to bottom-right corner.

The function has a couple of not required parameters:

```
selectROI(windowName, img[, showCrosshair[, fromCenter]]) -> retval
```

- param `windowName` name of the window where selection process will be
  shown.
- param `img` image to select a ROI.
- param `showCrosshair` if true crosshair of selection rectangle will be
  shown.
- param `fromCenter` if true center of selection will match initial mouse
  position. In opposite case a corner of selection rectangle will
  correspond to the initial mouse position.

returns selected ROI or empty rect if selection canceled.

Controls: use `space` or `enter` to finish selection, use key `c` to cancel selection.

Overloaded function doesn't require `windowName`.

```
selectROI(img[, showCrosshair[, fromCenter]]) -> retval
```